# Finding XML text values with spaces using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

How to find the `Fetus Summary` node using xpath?

```xml
<container flag="SEPARATE">
            <relationship>CONTAINS</relationship>
            <concept>
              <value>125008</value>
              <scheme>
                <designator>DCM</designator>
              </scheme>
              <meaning>Fetus Summary</meaning>
            </concept>
</container>
```

This doesn't work:

```ruby
xml.xpath( '//*[.="Fetus Summary"]' )
```

But similar code does, when using text values without spaces.  Can someone please help?

Comment: XPath is correct. Can you try this: `//*[normalize-space(.)="Fetus Summary"]`

Comment: Yes, that works.. on the snippet, but it appears my problem is deeper.  It still doesn't work on the full XML document, which validates in all othe respects.  Does the header of the document make a difference?  It's <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<report type="Comprehensive SR">

Comment: By the way, you can post this an answer and I'll accept it.  I probably have some work to do re-constructing the document bit by bit to see where it fails.

Comment: Posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `normalize-space()` function, e.g.:

```
//*[normalize-space(.)="Fetus Summary"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code works just fine with the XML that you have shared:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML '
    <container flag="SEPARATE">
                <relationship>CONTAINS</relationship>
                <concept>
                  <value>125008</value>
                  <scheme>
                    <designator>DCM</designator>
                  </scheme>
                  <meaning>Fetus Summary</meaning>
                </concept>
    </container>
'

puts doc.at_xpath( '//*[.="Fetus Summary"]' )
#=> <meaning>Fetus Summary</meaning>
```

This works even if you have the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` at the start of the document.

My guess is that your document has whitespace characters that look like spaces or tabs but are not. From where are you getting your XML? (Over the Internet using `open-uri`, or from a file?) Can you please post the result of `p my_xml_string` to your question, which will encode any complex characters?